# apache mod_jk configuration for ssl tomcat6

Tags: apache, tomcat6, mod-jk

I am trying to update my webserver from mod_proxy to mod_jk.

I am able to access http pages using following configurations
    
    JkMount /* loadbalancer

and my workers.properties are

```
worker.list=loadbalancer,status  
Define Node1  
worker.node1.port=8009  
worker.node1.host=10.255.255.77  
worker.node1.type=ajp13  
worker.node1.lbfactor=1  
worker.node1.cachesize=10  
worker.loadbalancer.type=lb  
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=node1  
worker.loadbalancer.sticky_session=1  
worker.list=loadbalancer  
worker.status.type=status
```

For our SSL tomcat is listening on diffrent port, so how can I pass this ssl to diffrent port. How I need to configure workers.properties.

My tomcat configurations are

Can you guide me on SSL please?

Sreenivas

Answer (score 0):

Created new worker and assigned SSL port 8010. In ssl virtual host  we mounted that worker.

Sreenivas